# Help Solving a Integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need a help solving this integration equation,$$\int {y \over  \sqrt{1+y^2}} dy$$

I am quite weak with maths. I would really appreciate if someone would guide me solving this.

Comment: Try computing the derivative of $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u=1+y^2$.

Then:

> $du=2y\,dy\implies {1\over 2}\,du=y\,dy$

And:

> $$\displaystyle{\int{y\over \sqrt{1+y^2}}\,dy={1\over 2}\int {du\over \sqrt u}=  {1\over 2}\int u^{-1/2}\,du={1\over 2}{u^{1/2}\over 1/2}+C=\sqrt{1+y^2}+C.}$$

Comment: kudos! I wish i could think this stuff

Answer (score 2):

First check that

$$\int\frac{f'(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{f(x)}}=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C\,\,,\,\,C=\text{ a constant}$$

and now just observe that

$$y=\frac{1}{2}2y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy}(1+y^2)=\frac{1}{2}(1+y^2)'$$

Answer (score 0):

You may also substitute $y=\tan(\theta)$, and $dy=\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$.
$$\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} dy=\int \frac{\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta=\int \tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)d\theta=\sec(\theta)$$
$$\sec(\theta)=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)}=\sqrt{1+y^2}$$
So the answer is $\sqrt{1+y^2}+C$.